# Get a single list of videos from different youtube channels subscriptions

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I have a list of youtube channels which I am subscribed to, and I want to get the uploaded videos in these channels in a list using Youtube Data Api in my android app. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please share what you have done and where you stuck

Comment: i get the list of youtube subscribed channels but i dont have any idea how can i get all videos of these channels in one list to show in android app

Comment: @Ashir You want to get different youtube channels videos in one same list?

Comment: Format the question, make it easy to understand

Comment: @LuisAguilar yes i want to get different channels videos in one single list

Comment: @DrissBounouar, Actually i want to get the upload videos of channels in one list, but i have many channels not only one channel

Comment: @Ashir that's exactly what's the question explains now.

Comment: I didn't get any solution for this yet, kindly share your experience.